# jQuery Slick Slider: How to scroll less than one entire slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Using [Slick Slider](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) I'm trying to create a carousel that on the first slide it will show 75% of the slide and when scrolling it should only show 75% of the next slide.

**First slide only showing 75% and then 25% of next slide**
[image]

**What is happening: Shows 75% of next slide but does not show 25% of previous slide**
[image]

**What I am trying to accomplish: Show 25% of the previous slide and 75% of current slide**
[image]

My current **Slick Config** is:

```js
$('.myCarousel').slick({
    arrows: false,
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 0.75,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true
})
```

I've tried changing the `slidesToScroll` property to `0.75` with zero success. It seems that anything less than `1` and **Slick Slider** refuses to change slides.

I've also found that I can have my slider element, in this example `.myCarousel`, watch for the `swipe` event. I've thought about attempting to change the `transform: translation(#px, #px, #px)` on the carousel container, `.myCarousel`, with JS but I feel there must be an easier way.

**Carousel HTML**

```html
<div class="gateway_nav">
    <div class="border_right__red">
        <div>
            <a href="" class="gateway_nav__gateway_title">ASD</a>
        </div>
        <div class="gateway_nav__slider_element">
            <a href="">ASDFG</a>
        </div>
        <div class="gateway_nav__slider_element">
            <a href="">ASDFGH</a>
        </div>
        <div class="gateway_nav__slider_element">
            <a href="">ASDFGHJKL</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="" class="gateway_nav__gateway_title">QWERT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="gateway_nav__slider_element">
            <a href="">QWERT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="gateway_nav__slider_element">
            <a href="">QWERTY</a>
        </div>
        <div class="gateway_nav__slider_element">
            <a href="">QWER</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you have any html with this?

Comment: @Keith added HTML to the end thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is play with the center padding:

```
$('.gateway_nav').slick({
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '20%',
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/10ftk4w2/

I don't have your CSS so I'm guessing here.